# Joomla 3.3 specific menu item nofollow

Tags: php, joomla-3.3.x, menu-item

I want to add `rel="nofollow"` to certain menu items in Joomla menu. I do not want to change Joomla core files. What I want is to put in menu options nofollow for "Link Type" tab "Link Title Attribute" and then in menu overrides to check with help of php if the link has title tag and nofollow attribute in it replace it with `rel="nofollow"`.

I managed to do this with jQuery, but I am afraid for some search engines not to consider jQuery, so I would like to do this server side.

Is there a way to get this?

Thanks

Comment: This question is also asked on SO here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854648/joomla-3-3-specific-menu-item-nofollow/23859123#23859123 .  Please dont ask your question on more than one forum. (see in meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu )

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Edit the menu item from Admin, and go to the Metadata tab. Below the metadata description and keywords is a droptdown of the Robot options, including NoIndex, NoFollow

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not a solution for me. This will prevent the page from indexing. I do not want this, I just want to have my link to this page nofollow for link juice.

Answer (score 1):

If I dont want to make a new menu module for a task like this I tend to reuse the class on the item. 
Then in a mod_menu override I then put an (if strpos($item->anchor_css, 'no-follow') !== false) { ## your adding html }

/templates/dogstrapv1/html/mod_menu/default.php and its sub overrides like default_url.php

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own menu module and do whatever you want there.
The only limitation is that you need to work with the present parameters from the menu item. However some people get creative with them :)